# API for ical in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am devloping application in which i require API for ical(like on  mac) for iphone , if someone has come across such API or sample code , please provide me the same .
If this question is already asked please redirect me to the same .

Comment: Actually i was looking for ical which is available in our mac os .I found out solution something like this .I took a scroll view and loaded the view in that scrollview and created the dynamic label based on the start date and end date and set the frame of label and added that label on to the view which did the trick for me .Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Event Kit Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can access the calendar events using [EKEvent Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/EventKit/Reference/EKEventClassRef/Reference/Reference.html). For details refer [EventKit documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009765)